# Why would MySQL execute return None?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to query on a local MySQL database using Python's (3.4) MySQL module with the following code:

```
class databases():

  def externaldatabase(self):

  try:
    c = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="user",
                                password="password", database="database")
     if c.is_connected():
           c.autocommit = True
      return(c)
    except:
         return(None)
    d = databases().externaldatabase()
    c = d.cursor() 
    r = c.execute('''select * from tbl_wiki''')
    print(r) 
> Returns: None
```

As far as I can tell, the connection is successful, the database is composed of several rows but the query always returns the none type.

What instances does the MySQL execute function return None?

Comment: `c.execute()` doesn't return anything unless you use the `multi=True` option. Then it returns an iterator that lets you step through the results of each query in the multiple queries.

Comment: Normally you call methods on the cursor to get the results out of the query, e.g. `c.fetchone()` to get one row, `c.fetchall()` to get all the results.

Comment: See the documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html

Comment: Which MySQL interface are you using? In general, with Python DB-API database libraries, `execute` returns `None`. (The DB-API spec just says "Return values are undefined".) The point of `execute` is to modify the cursor so you can extract rows from it, and in Python, methods that modify an object normally return `None`. Some libraries do have return values for `execute` in certain cases for shortcuts or additional functionality, but if you're not using any of those cases, you shouldn't expect anything meaningful from `execute`.

Comment: @Barmar I have done that, however, fetchone() would return an error as None does not have the attribute fetchone().

Comment: @BarryBrian Are you sure you're doing `c.fetchone()`, not `r.fetchone()`?

Comment: @Barmar You are correct, I was not referencing the cursor.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Query executions have no return values.

The pattern you need to follow is:

```
cursor creation;
cursor, execute query;
cursor, *fetch rows*;
```

Or in python:

```py
c = d.cursor()

c.execute(query)    # selected rows stored in cursor memory

rows = c.fetchall()    # get all selected rows, as Barmar mentioned
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

Also some db modules allow you to iterate over the cursor using the for...in pattern, but triple-check that regarding mysql.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I return the `cursor` as I need the value to return a `string` specifically, for instance, I return the password (string) for inspect whether user used the same password twice. Here's how I did it (In my case):

```py
def getUserPassword(metadata):
    cursorObject.execute("SELECT password FROM users WHERE email=%s AND password=%s LIMIT 1", (metadata['email'], metadata['password']))
    return cursorObject.fetchall()[0]['password']
```

Which I can  easily call from another `class` by calling the method:

```py
assert getUserPassword({"email" : "email", "password" : "oldpass"}) is not None
```

And which the `getUserPassword` itself is returning a `string`