# MySQL-Python connector attribute error for cursor object

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm using the mysql-connector-python package for a project in Flask. For the signup routing portion, I want MySQL to check if a username already exists, and if it does, I'll set an error. My code looks like this:

```
@bp.route('/signup', methods=('POST',))
def signup():

    ...

    username = reqObj["username"]
    password = reqObj["password"]
    error = None

    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT * FROM userinfo " 
        "WHERE username=%s")

    existingUser = cursor.execute(query, (username,)).fetchone()

    if existingUser is not None:
        error = "Username already exists"

    if error is None:
        cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO userinfo (username, password) VALUES (%s, %s)',
            (username, generate_password_hash(password))
        )

        cursor.close()
        db.commit()

        res = {'actionSuccess': True}
        return jsonify(res)
    else:
        res = {'actionSuccess': False, 'error': error}
        return jsonify(res)
```

The get_db() function returns the mysql.connector.connect() object. However, when I run this on a server and test it, I get an error in Flask saying:

```
...
existingUser = cursor.execute(query, (username,)).fetchone()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchone'
```

So I figure my error is somewhere with my cursor.execute(), which I'm guessing is returning a NoneType. So I delete the fetchone() function and try again, but now I get this error instead:

```
...
File "e:\flasktest2\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1128, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found
```

This is confusing even further, because it's now saying that there are unread results, when a moment ago the cursor.execute() was a NoneType. I don't know what's causing the error. I then tried commenting out the whole SELECT query section, and just tested to see if the INSERT would work, and sure enough it did. What's causing my errors?

Comment: You are breaking the statement here `query = ("SELECT * FROM userinfo " 
        "WHERE username=%s")`. try something like this `query = ("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username=%s")`

Comment: Apparently `execute()` on a mysql.connector Cursor object returns `None` unless it is called with [`multi=True`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html). Try `cursor.execute(query, (username,))` and then `existingUser = cursor.fetchone()` individually. As for the `Unread results found`, this is somehwat explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffered.html).

Comment: @shmee Hey yea I just figured this out myself! For some reason, cursor.execute() will complete the action, return None, and then store the results in the cursor object itself. So I have to use fetchone on the cursor obj, not on cursor.execute()

Comment: This behavior seems to differ between the modules. With `sqlite3` it is perfectly fine to do `cursor.execute(<SQL>).fetchone()` because `execute` returns the cursor object it is called from. In `pymysql`, `execute` returns the number of affected rows. [PEP 249 does not define return values for `execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#execute). The result of a query is always at least referenced in the cursor, so that `c.execute*(); c.fetch*()` will work with any DBAPI2 compliant module.

Comment: @albert: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421466/why-would-mysql-execute-return-none

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, with the mysql connector, cursor.execute(...) will return None, no matter what the results of executing the statements are. However, the results WILL be stored in the cursor object itself, even if the result is an empty set. You must also fetch all results for the current query before using the cursor to execute new statements on the new connection as well. This means doing:

```
cursor.execute(...)
cursor.fetchone()
```

as opposed to:

```
cursor.execute(...).fetchone()
```